# Perl: Hash not storing information correctly

Tags: perl, hash

I have a strange issue with hashes/arrays within perl, I'm reading in some data but when i read out the data it seems it has only recorded the last few items over the top of all the records.

I'll try to demo the system below, this is not an exact copy of my code as the data i am using is sensitive:

the value of $data[6] can vary which confirms the error

```
my @store = array();
my @data = array(columns1....1000);

# Overall loop
for(my $counter = 0; $i <= $2; $counter++) 
{
   # loop dataset
   for(my $record = 0; $record <= $100; $record++) 
   {


      $store[$counter][$record]->{$data[6]} = $data[100];


    }
}
```

Comment: `$2`, `$100` ?? Also you are using `$i` from nowhere.

Comment: Please provide working code with some sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you cannot post code... here try to debug by printing the value of hash at intermediate stage using Data::Dumper http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/Data-Dumper-2.121/Dumper.pm

Comment: That code looks like php to me, not perl.

Comment: When you want to figure something out, write small (and working) test programs to demonstrate the issue. This code doesn't "demo" anything.

Comment: @briandfoy it demos that he doesn't know Perl very well. 1) He doesn't show a match of any kind and 2) I'm skeptical that he has *100* captures in the regex as to account for `$100` in the inner loop.

Comment: @RobK: He probably defined `sub array{@_}` somewhere. ;) But yeah, it looks like some kind of mash-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As codaddict pointed out in a comment, you have an error in your loop indexes - `$2` is a variable (probably undefined), not the integer 2.

However, it generally is a code smell in Perl to use explicit array indexes.  You should instead build up your data structure in a more natural fashion:

```
my @store = map {
    [
        map {
            # some logic here which fills in the second dimension of data        
        } (1..100);
    ]
} (1..2);
```

Comment: I have to say that nested `map`'s do not feel natural to me, and I have a much harder time reading code that does that.  This may of course just be my problem...

Comment: @flies: It's probably a matter of taste. I think nested `map`s are more readable than `for` loops when doing something as simple as this.

Comment: If you prefer `for` loops, try doing `foreach my $record (0 .. 100)` instead of `for (my $record = 0; $record <= 100; $record++)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're storing a reference to `$data[$record]` rather than the value.

If your data stores references to a scalar then `$$data[$record]` will [dereference](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html) it, similarly `@{data[$record]}` and `%{data[$record]}` for arrays and hashes.

Comment: I generally prefer to use and see `$data->[$record]` over `$$data[$record]`.